# Requesting for missing files is what type of exception

Tags: java, exception

Requesting for missing files is what type of exception.
Is it checked or unchecked.

Comment: What is requesting the files?

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the requesting code? That way we can diagnose what type of exception might be thrown.

Comment: It could be anything and should be documented in the method you are using...

Answer (score 4):

If you mean the  [FileNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html), the documentation shows it does not extend RuntimeException, so it is a checked exception.  You can easily tell whether any exception is Checked or Unchecked by looking at what it extends.  "Error" or "RuntimeException" are unchecked, and IIR everything else is checked.

Comment: Valuable info for checked/unchecked exception confusion. +1.

Answer (score 1):

When you get an exception at compile time of the program, it was a checked exception. Here file existence is verified by the jvm at compile time for processing the contents of this file.